# AdMob banner aligned on bottom is very near of back, home and menu buttons in Android 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, admob

In the guides of how to put a correct banner from AdMob guidelines, they told that the best place to put it is aligned in the bottom of the screen. I am doing that in all my apps, allways.

I noticed that in Android 4.4 kitkat, the banner is extremely near of the screeen buttons of back, home and menu. I attach a image in the next lines.

Is this dangerous??? Can my account be banned for this?

Thanks

Image:

[image]

Comment: Try adding padding to the bottom of the ad and/or layout margins.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think it can be banned for something as minimal as this, but to be safe, you could add paddings at the bottom of the screen so that there is a little screen space before you touch the hardware buttons.

The things that could get you banned would be making an automatic click on the banner periodically to get CPM, that is very dangerous and unethical. If you are also uncomfortable with it being down the screen, you could put it on top to be safe. I hope I helped you